# Add taxonomy column with meta field (ACF) content

Tags: custom-taxonomy, array, columns

Trying to populate the column with meta field, this way (ACF):

```
add_filter('manage_artist_custom_column', function ($content,$column_name,$term_id){
    $term= get_term($term_id, 'artist');
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'artist_avatar':
            $avatar = get_field('artist_avatar', $term);
            var_dump($avatar);
            $content = $avatar['url'];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $content;
},10,3);

add_filter( 'manage_edit-artist_columns', function ( $columns ) {
    $columns['artist_avatar'] = __('Artist Avatar', 'sage');
    return $columns;
} );
```

When I `var_dump($avatar);` I get the output:

```
array(24) {
  ["ID"]=&gt;
  int(315)
  ["id"]=&gt;
  int(315)
  ["title"]=&gt;
  string(16) "bigote-sucio-pic"
  ["filename"]=&gt;
  string(20) "bigote-sucio-pic.jpg"
  ["filesize"]=&gt;
  int(238431)
  ["url"]=&gt;
  string(66) "https://futurabasura.test/app/uploads/2021/04/bigote-sucio-pic.jpg"
  etc …
  etc …
```

But, if I try to access any of the array keys:

```
$content = $avatar['url'];
```

I get `"Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"`

Why?

Comment: And what does `var_dump( get_field('artist_avatar', $term) );` output? A boolean? But this looks like an issue using the ACF function, so the question doesn't really fit in here.

Comment: The output of `var_dump( get_field('artist_avatar', $term) )` is the same of `var_dump($avatar)`. Note that `$avatar = get_field('artist_avatar', $term);`. I dont know why I can't access the array elements. It is very strange.

Comment: In that case, then the error might be for a different term, so I suggest you to validate the return value, e.g. `if ( is_array( $avatar ) ) { access the array items }`. Even if that doesn't fix the issue, you should ensure `$avatar` is actually an array and that an item you're accessing is set.

Comment: Totally right! The error come from the terms with `artist_avatar` field empty. Thank you very much. do you like to put an answer? if not, I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Sally CJ suggest in comments, the error come from the terms with `artist_avatar`
empty. So, check if `is_array()` before access the array, fix it:

```
add_filter('manage_artist_custom_column', function ($content,$column_name,$term_id){
    $term = get_term($term_id, 'artist');
    $avatar = get_field('artist_avatar', $term);

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'artist_avatar':
            if ( is_array( $avatar ) ) {
                $content = $avatar["url"];
            } else {
                $content = __('This artist has no picture', 'sage');
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $content;
},10,3);
```